# ayuda con input hidden y value en php

Tags: php

Hola amigos necesito ayuda con este código.
Lo que tengo es un buscador que arroja registros de la base de datos dentro de la misma página, hasta ahí funciona bien. 
cada registro lleva un botón/link para ingresar a ver los detalles a otra página. 
El problema que tengo es que no logro pasar las variables a la otra página.

buscador:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['buscar'])){

$_POST['profesiones'];
$_POST['com'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM prof WHERE (comuna1 = '$_POST[com]' OR comuna2 = '$_POST[com]' OR comuna3 = '$_POST[com]' OR comuna4 = '$_POST[com]') AND (especializacion = '$_POST[profesiones]') ");
while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<form name="detalles" method="POST" action="detalles.php">
 <td><input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $consulta['id'];?>"><?php echo $consulta['id'];?></td>
<input type="submit" name="ver" value="submit"></td>      
<?php }

}
?>
```

---

Los resultados me los arroja bien dentro de la misma página pero al enviarlos a la otra no logro hacerlo, me envía un mismo id fijo y no el que le corresponde al producto.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiarlo así

```
 <td><input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $consulta['id'];?>"><?php echo $consulta['id'];?></td>
```

No le estás mandando a imprimir el dato en el `value=` por lo tanto no toma ningún dato, espero que te pueda ayudar, saludos

Comment: Puede también usar la sintaxis de impresión rápida, <?= $consulta['id']; ?>, asi se ahorra el echo

Comment: pero el valor se lo estoy dando con el echo en el value, ¿de que otra manera podría imprimírselo?

Comment: Pues como lo estás mostrando ahí en el post, en el `value=` no le estás haciendo el `echo` a `$consulta['id'];` o tampoco mandandoselo con el metodo que dice darioxlz, entonces no está tomando ningún valor

Comment: Disculpa mi error, escribí mal el código acá. efectivamente si lo tengo con echo aun así no me envía el id hacia la pagina de action, ya que cuando lo imprimo en ésta me arroja un mismo id para todas las consultas.

Comment: Ya hiciste un `var_dump($_POST['id']);` para ver que es lo que te arroja en `detalles.php`?

Comment: var_dump = string(2) "25" 25 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Por la URL pasan perfectamente todos los datos, despues los imprimo con $_GET pero con POST no los logro enviar, ya ni idea de que puede ser.

Comment: Bueno solucioné el problema, la verdad no se que carajos tiene que ver pero la <table></table> me estaba dando problemas, los códigos fuera de ésta funcionan, dentro no.

Comment: de lado de la página de donde recibes el dato lo estas haciendo de forma correcta ?  Usaste $_GET ?

Comment: Si todo bien el error estaba en la página desde donde enviaba los datos, tenía mal cerrado un isset} más arriba de donde debía estar. mucho cansancio afecta! gracias a todos por los comentarios!!!